# Unwanted Rows Created When Opening XML Derived Data Using XSL Stylesheet

Tags: excel, xml, xslt, row

We have data from a RestAPI command using an XSL stylesheet that populates a browser in a nicely formatted manner. In the browser case, the "Description" field/column occupies ONE (1) block/cell regardless of how many lines breaks, paragraph elements, or lists are present.

When exporting the browser XML to a file with an old XLS extension and providing the same XSL stylesheet (in the same folder for simplicity), the Excel sheet created (with table) behaves as expected with the local stylesheet EXCEPT extra rows are generated in the Description column wherever a line break, paragraph element, or list is present (among other possibilities not mentioned for simplicity). Interestingly, all the other cells in the table where extra rows are present are automatically merged. Also, this could happen to any column with multiline data.

When creating an Excel table where we can sort all of the data (with associated "Description") we now have an impossible problem in that only the first chunk (before a break element) of the Description gets carried with the sorted rows, and the rest of the data in the extra rows is left orphaned an unsortable.

Obviously, we are looking for a solution where all the multi-line "Description" data stays in a SINGLE CELL when opening in Excel. I have provided the complete code for the Excel 97 "Multiline_Excel_Issue.xls" XML data and the "TableXMLstylesheet.xsl" stylesheet that need to be in the same folder. When opening the XLS file, it will ask for the stylesheet and complain about a few things and open in protected mode with gridlines off. This can be overcome in trust settings.

I am suspecting that some modification to the line <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/> near the end of the XSL stylesheet will be the key to grouping all of the multiline "Description" data together, but all ideas are welcome. (As a side note, everyone should understand if multiline text is wrapped in quotes and pasted into an Excel cell it behaves and stays in a single cell).

This is what the Excel sheet looks like with the extra unwanted lines generated.

[image: Current unwanted extra rows]

This is what the desired output of the Excel sheet would look like if the stylesheet was fixed (without the extra unwanted lines generated).

[image: Desired Excel Output]

For the RestAPI XML Data as an Excel 97 file, copy the block below and Save As "Multiline_Excel_Issue.xls"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TableXMLstylesheet.xsl"?>
<Assets>
  <Asset id="Single:01">
    <Attribute name="Description">This is a statement with a single line "as in single" line.&amp;nbsp; At this time I have no plans to change this line.&lt;br&gt;</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name">Single line has no issues</Attribute>
  </Asset>
  <Asset id="Multi:01">
    <Attribute name="Description">This description has multiple lines separated by these BR line break objects. I want all the rows generated in Excel to go away/gone never to be seen. This does not show up in the browser. How can we fix the xsl stylesheet??.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Thank you for helping me understand the issue.&amp;nbsp; It will be a great accomplishement to fix this problem.&lt;br&gt;</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name">Multiline HTML with line break elements</Attribute>
  </Asset>
  <Asset id="Empty:01">
    <Attribute name="Description" />
    <Attribute name="Name">This has no lines in Description</Attribute>
  </Asset>
  <Asset id="Multi:02">
    <Attribute name="Description">&lt;p&gt;See https://someuselesswebsitedonotbotherclicking.com/dummy/index.php?title=Title_one/Status_one#Making_it_Work&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;It would be great if this multiline example would show up in a single cell in Excel. Need to determine the cause/issue.&lt;/p&gt;</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name">Multiline HTML with paragraph elements and URLs</Attribute>
  </Asset>
  <Asset id="Multi:03">
    <Attribute name="Description">&lt;p&gt;This description has some multiline auto-generated numbering:&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;ol&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;This is the first line of the auto-numbered section/region.&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;And this is the second&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;And so on and so on and so on (will it stop?).&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;/ol&gt;</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name">Multiline HTML with auto line numbering elements</Attribute>
  </Asset>
</Assets>
```

For the XSL Stylesheet, copy the block below and Save As "TableXMLstylesheet.xsl"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Multiline Excel Issue</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .columnheader {
                                background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .8);
                                border-style: solid;
                                border-color: blue;
                            }
                    .column {
                                background: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0);
                                vertical-align: top;
                                border-style: solid;
                                border-color: red;
                            }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Assets" />
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="columnheader">AssetID</td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Assets/Asset[1]/child::*">
                                <td class="columnheader"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Assets/Asset" mode="Row" />
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>     
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Assets" />
    <xsl:template match="Asset" mode="Row">
        <tr>
            <td class="column">
                <a><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></a>
            </td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute">
        <td class="column">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Snippet of HTML produced when saving the desired result XLS file to HTML. This is for cell B3:

```html
<td class="xl68" width="256" style="border-top:none;border-left:none;width:192pt">This
  description has multiple lines separated by these BR line break objects. I
  want all the rows generated in Excel to go away/gone never to be seen. This
  does not show up in the browser. How can we fix the xsl stylesheet??.<br>
    <br>
    Thank you for helping me understand the issue.&nbsp; It will be a great
  accomplishement to fix this problem.</td>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what your question is about. Is it merely a matter of removing the `<br>` elements contained in the (escaped) HTML of the source? That shouldn't be too difficult (although it would be much easier if you could use an XSLT 3.0 processor).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for reviewing the post. We do not want to have to manipulate or remove anything. Imagine millions of assets with multi-millions of orphaned rows (and not just this 5 asset example). We need to fix the stylesheet so that the Description data stays in one cell per asset row.

Comment: Well, an XSL transformation by definition manipulates the XML input data. My question is how exactly the data needs to be manipulated **by the stylesheet** so that the result of the transformation satisfies your requirement. If you don't know that, then your question is not about XSLT (at least not yet). If you do, please edit your question and add the exact result you want to get (as HTML code) at the end of the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am new to this and am attempting to add a picture of how we desire the output to look. One row each for all AssetID, Description, and Name. I am hoping a picture is sufficient to convey our desire. I will work on attaching the picture.

Comment: No, a picture is useless for this. Find out what the HTML code needs to be so that the result in Excel is what you need.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead. AFAICT, your stylesheet already produces this result or one very similar to it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks & I moved the comment w/ code above into the last part of the question. The issue persists on four machines running various Excel versions with the stylesheet. It always produces the unwanted rows as in the 1st graphic. We create sortable tables of these assets thousands of rows and we can't be leaving large amounts of the Description data orphaned behind. I am hoping someone can figure out the piece of code that will put a wrapper around any Attribute column to keep it all together in Excel. Quotes around the block work in the real world when you paste it from Notepad.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I appreciate your input. I wish I could change the workflow, but we are stuck with the RestAPI XML data and the stylesheet. We can change the stylesheet. I will look into your suggestions, but if we could get some more eyes on this issue, I feel there may be a simple wrapper solution out there. If you know anyone in the forum, I would appreciate it. There is always a solution!

Comment: I see 2 major problems here. First, we don't know what causes the extra rows. It could be the `br` elements or the `p` elements or the `li` elements or just some or all of them. The other problem is that we are dealing with escaped HTML code. With the possible exception of `br`, it will be extremely difficult, if not impossible, to remove those elements using a single-pass XSLT 1.0 transformation (which is all you can do in a browser). XSLT is designed to deal with actual XML/HTML. All you can do here is apply some string functions to the markup and that's not expected to succeed.